# How do I determine the update site/source of an installed Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How do I determine the update site/source of an installed Eclipse plugin?

For example, in one of my development versions of Eclipse I have the plugin org.hamcrest.library. From *Help - About Eclipse - Installation Details - Plug-ins* I can determine that the provider is Eclipse.org, but is it possible to determine the feature or update site from where it came so I can install this in a separate version of Eclipse I have?

Answer (score 0):

All third-party open source bundles that are used by Eclipse are managed by [Orbit](http://www.eclipse.org/orbit/) project. You can install them from Orbit Repository.

Comment: Is there an update site for the Orbit project? Or just a manual download and copy to the plugins directory?

Comment: @tukushan, I also don't find the repository of Orbit, you can download them, then put them in the dropin folder of eclipse. I guess they're independent bundles, don't have a good way to organize them as feature/category.